# Why do memory instructions take 4 cycles in ARM assembly?

Tags: performance, assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, cpu-cycles

Memory instructions such as `ldr`, `str` or `b` take 4 cycles each in ARM assembly.

Is it because each memory location is 4 bytes long?

Comment: Depends a lot on the CPU, some ARM processors can probably execute more than one LDR or STR instructions in a cycle.

Comment: No it probably doesn't work that was (reading one byte/cycle, therefore taking 4 cycles), it's probably just straight up latency for the entire operation.

Comment: The width of data does rarely make big difference in performance, as you can throw "simply" more transistors to handle bigger width, instead of 8 bits in parallel you work with 16 or 32 in parallel. That costs "just" few additional millions of transistors over whole core, and that's how CPUs did move through 4, 8, 16, 32 to modern 64 bit (with dedicated 128-512 bit SIMD instructions units to even further parallelize). But it's difficult to "cheat" (cache is one) the whole logical complexity of contacting different chip (memory) from CPU to fetch/store some data over bus. It's like travelling.

Comment: ARM is a pipelined architecture. Each clock cycle advances the pipeline by one step. When viewed in aggregate, it can execute most instructions in 1 clock, but the start to finish of each instruction is longer. See this diagram from ARM: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0222b/ch01s01s01.html

Comment: @BitBank Your comment could be made into an answer :)

Comment: @BitBank Thank you. Your comment should indeed be an answer!

Comment: What is your reference for '4 cycles'?

Comment: @artlessnoise My computer architecture lectures about arm 7 architecture.

Comment: @ChrisTang: the [tag:cycles] tag isn't about clock cycles.  Also, this question is about performance of specific microarchitectures, not the ISA, so [tag:instruction-set] isn't a good fit either.  Thanks for adding code-formatting to the question body, though.  I think [performance] and [cpu-cycles] tags would fit better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ARM has a pipelined architecture. Each clock cycle advances the pipeline by one step (e.g. fetch/decode/execute/read...). Since the pipeline is continuously fed, the overall time to execute each instruction can approach 1 cycle, but the actual time for an individual instruction from 'fetch' through completion can be 3+ cycles. ARM has a good explanation on their website:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0222b/ch01s01s01.html

Memory latency adds another layer of complication to this idea. ARM employs a multi-level cache system which aims to have the most frequently used data available in the fewest cycles. Even a read from the fastest (L0) cache involves several cycles of latency. The pipeline includes facilities to allow read requests to complete at a later time if the data is not used right away. It's easier to understand by way of example:

```
LDR R0,[R1]
MOV R2,R3    // Allow time for memory read to occur
ADD R4,R4,#200  // by interleaving other instructions
CMP R0,#0  // before trying to use the value

// By trying to access the data immediately, this will cause a pipeline
// 'stall' and waste time waiting for the data to become available.
LDR R0,[R1]
CMP R0,#0 // Wastes at least 1 cycle due to pipeline not having the data
```

The idea is to hide the inherent latencies in the pipeline and, if you can, hide additional latencies in the memory access by delaying dependencies on registers (aka instruction interleaving).

Comment: Additional points?  There is no latency with a store.  Also, things are faster with a cache is both code and data.  Code will initially compete with the data accesses.  There is the `PLD` instruction.  Branches can complicate things.

Comment: @artlessnoise - Mostly true. There are only 4 write buffers which don't coalesce sequential writes. Poor use of write buffers (e.g. writing 1 byte at a time) will cause extra stalls on writes too.

Comment: Heads up, the link is broken. To see the old version, here's an [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200518031316/http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0222b/ch01s01s01.html).